# D3 histogram, number of occurrences of date from time stamp

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Newb here. I have a csv with this data:

```
date, lat, lon
01/01/2015 09:38:14 AM,37.973424,-87.575423
01/01/2015 09:48:27 PM,37.385218,-122.11413
01/01/2015 10:17:34 AM,39.081712,-76.554603
01/02/2015 01:27:17 PM,40.216204,-74.619533
```

I want to have a histogram where the x axis is by date and the y axis is by number of occurrences.

So Jan 1 would have a column height of 3 and Jan 2 would have a column height of 1. The time of day is irrelevant.

Do I need to parse the dates, or set a [time interval](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals) of "day" somehow, or create an array? It seems there are two steps: "filter" the data into chunks, and count the chunks, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/j3LzY/), but the dates are already "rounded" nicely to dates, and the data is in the file, not external.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is iterate through your data and keep a tally of the frequencies. I modified this [bar chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) to use your data. You need to use the [Time Formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) methods D3 provides.

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p");

// line = "01/01/2015 09:38:14 AM,37.973424,-87.575423"

var parts = line.split(',');
var datetime = formatDate.parse(parts[0]);
var date = formatDate(datetime).split(' ')[0]; // "01/01/2015"
```

**Full example:**

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
},
width = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var csv = [
'01/01/2015 09:38:14 AM,37.973424,-87.575423',
'01/01/2015 09:48:27 PM,37.385218,-122.11413',
'01/01/2015 10:17:34 AM,39.081712,-76.554603',
'01/02/2015 01:27:17 PM,40.216204,-74.619533'
];

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p");

var tally = {};

csv.forEach(function(line) {
    var parts = line.split(',');
    var datetime = formatDate.parse(parts[0]);
    var date = formatDate(datetime).split(' ')[0];
    
    tally[date] = (tally[date]||0) + 1;
});

var data = [];

for (var date in tally) {
    if (tally.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        data.push({
            date: date,
            frequency: tally[date]
        });
    }
}

x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.frequency;
})]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.date);
})
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
})
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
});


function type(d) {
    d.frequency = +d.frequency;
    return d;
}
```

```css
.bar {
    fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover {
    fill: brown;
}
.axis {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2fuwa64k/1/)**

Loading from CSV file:

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p");

var tally = {};
var data = [];

d3.csv('./data.csv')
.get(function(error, rows) {

  rows.forEach(function(obj, i) {
    var datetime = formatDate.parse(obj.date);
    var date = formatDate(datetime).split(' ')[0];
    tally[date] = (tally[date]||0) + 1;
  });

  for (var date in tally) {
    if (tally.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        data.push({
            date: date,
            frequency: tally[date]
        });
    }
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Much appreciated! A quick followup question. You have the data in "var = csv". My data is in a 20,000 row external csv file. How do I connect the two? I tried wrapping your forEach function in the d3.csv, but something isn't working. (sorry, I also can't seem to get this code to appear in a block):  `d3.csv("data/test.csv", function(error, line) {
    forEach(function(line) {
        var parts = line.split(',');
        var datetime = formatDate.parse(parts[0]);
        var date = formatDate(datetime).split(' ')[0];
        
        tally[date] = (tally[date]||0) + 1;
    });
});`

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try it out and report back!

Comment: Thanks. I still have trouble with it, but I think that is my lack of experience, and not the updated answer you provided. I'll keep fiddling with it and if I get it going I'll let you know. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I just posted a new related question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020298/d3-slider-and-number-of-occurrences-in-csv). I mention it in case you might be willing to take a look, since your answer here was extremely helpful. No prob if not. Thanks!